# How to add multiple codeception suites to different folders in one project?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, codeception

I have the following folder structure, I want multiple test suites to exist in different directories.

```
- project
    - app
        - app-A
            - tests
                - (functional tests here)

        - app-B
            - tests
                - (functional tests here)

    - domains
        - domain-A
            - tests
                - (unit tests here)

        - domain-B
            - tests
                - (unit tests here)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. create `codeception.yml` file in the root directory of your project**

**2. past the following in that file:**

```
include:

  - 

paths:

  log: log

settings:

  colors: true
```

**3. generate the some test suites in on their sub directories:**

```
codecept bootstrap /.../src/Domains/User --namespace user

codecept bootstrap /.../src/Application/Cms --namespace cms
```

**4. update the  `codeception.yml` of the root directory by including the path to the test suite under the includes.**

```
include:

  - src/Domains/User

  - src/Application/Cms
```

**5. generate some tests**

```
codecept generate:cept --config src/Domains/User unit testB

codecept generate:cept --config src/Applications/Cms functional testA
```

**6. run the tests**

```
codecept run
```